# Using a theorem (which is originally set on 2-dim bounded domain in Euclidean space) on a torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Actually I'm reading a paper on mean-field equation on torus by M.Struwe and G.Tarantello [Here](https://www.math.kit.edu/iana1/lehre/varmeth2022w/media/struwe%20m.,%20tarantello%20g.%20-%20on%20multivortex%20solutions%20in%20chern-simons%20gauge%20theory.pdf), they studied $$\tag{1}
-\Delta u=\lambda\left(\frac{e^u}{\int_{\Omega} e^u d x}-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\right),
$$
on flat torus $\Omega$. They tried to use the following celebrated lemma by Brezis and Merle

> (Brezis-Merle). - Let $D$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and
> $\left\{w_n\right\}$ be a sequence satisfying: $$
>  -\Delta w_n=V_n(x) e^{w_n} \quad \text { on } D $$ with $0 \leqslant V_n(x) \leqslant b_1$ on D. Also suppose that $\int_D e^{w_n}
>  \leqslant b_2$. Then $\left\{w_n\right\}$ admits a subsequence
> $\left\{w_{n_k}\right\}$ satisfying one of the following:
>
> i) $\left\{w_{n_k}\right\}$ is uniformly locally bounded in $D$;
>
> ii) for any compact set $K \subset D$, there holds $$ \sup _K w_{n_k}
>  \rightarrow-\infty \quad \text { as } k \rightarrow+\infty ; $$
>
> iii) there exists $S=\left\{a_1, \ldots, a_p\right\} \subset D$ (blow
> up set) and a sequence $\left\{x_{n_k}^i\right\} \subset D$ such that,
> as $k \rightarrow \infty, x_{n_k}^i \rightarrow a_i,
>  w_{n_k}\left(x_{n_k}^i\right) \rightarrow \infty, i=1, \ldots, p$.
> Moreover, for any compact set $K \subset D \backslash S$ we have,
> $\sup w_{n_k} \rightarrow-\infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.
> (Li-Shafrir): In addition, if $V_n \rightarrow V$ in
> $C^0(\bar{\Omega})$, then  $$ V_{n_k} e^{w_{n_k}} \rightarrow
>  \sum_{i=1}^p 8 \pi m_i \delta_{x=a_i} $$ in the sense of measures,
> with $m_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta_{x=a_i}$ the Dirac distribution
> supported in $\left\{a_i\right\}, i=1, \ldots, p$.

Let $\lambda_n \rightarrow \lambda$ and let $u_n \in E$ be a solution for $(1)_{\lambda_n}$ . They deal the equation in the following way:
set
$$
u_n(0)=\sup _{\Omega} u_n,
$$
and let
$$\tag{2}
w_n(x)=u_n(x)-\ln \left(\int_{\Omega} e^{u_n} d x\right)-\frac{\lambda_n}{4}|x|^2 \text {, }
$$
with
$$
\int_{\Omega} e^{w_n} d x \leqslant 1 .
$$

Thus, the hypotheses of Lemma by Brezis-Merle are satisfied for $w_n$ with $V_n=\lambda_n e^{\left(\lambda_n / 4\right)|x|^2} \leqslant$ $\lambda_n e^{\lambda_n}, b_2=1$. (If we set $\lambda \in (8 \pi, 4 \pi^2)$, then (iii) can not occur.)

**But there is a problem, what the definition of the variable of $w_n$ in (2)?**, to satisfy the Brezis-Merle lemma, it should be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the variable on $u_n$ is on torus, how did they mixed these two things together?

**Or this $| \cdot |$ is a geodesic distance? If so, they then estimated $\sup _{B_{1 / 2}(0)} w_n$, is this $B_{1 / 2}(0)$ a geodesic ball?**

**Or does this mean that they just simply treated it as an equation on a square with opposite sites topologically identified**? In fact, in the beginning of the paper, they said Let $\Omega$ be the 2 -dimensional torus, with fundamental cell domain: $[-1 / 2,1 / 2] \times$ $[-1 / 2,1 / 2]$. Or, equivalently, solutions of $$
-\Delta u=\lambda\left(\frac{e^u}{\int_{\Omega} e^u d x}-1\right) \quad \text { on } \Omega
$$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of period 1 in each variable.

Comment: One can always go from a solution of a PDE on a torus to a solution of the same PDE on a fundamental domain, with matching boundary conditions on the boundary, just by composing the solution with the map from the fundamental domain to the torus, which is a smooth local isometry.

Comment: Going in the reverse direction requires more care because one wants the solution to stay regular on (the image of) the boundary. In the case of second order elliptic PDE such as this one, this generally requires not only that the boundary values agree on opposite sides, but that the normal derivatives are also compatible, and some additional regularity 
 or compatibility at the four corners may also be required.  However, none of this is needed for the question at hand, which is only going in the "easy" direction (from the torus to the fundamental domain, rather than vice versa).